# Decode conversation state in Google Assistant SDK

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I am making a AI app for fun. It classifies sentences, manages context and passes the query to corresponding app. I am trying to merge Google Assistant into that. Any ideas on how can I get what's in `conversation_state` blob that Google uses to track context?

Reference for [Google Assistant gRPC API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha1#google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha1.EmbeddedAssistant) explains conversation state as

> The conversation_state value returned in the prior ConverseResponse. Omit (do not set the field) if there was no prior ConverseResponse. If there was a prior ConverseResponse, do not omit this field; doing so will end that conversation (and this new request will start a new conversation).